# RESET procedure of 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

The reset pin of 8086 and other processors will cause the CS:IP to point to FFFF:0000 which is the lowest 16bytes of the memory. In that location there is a jump instruction to somewhere else in the memory space to initialize the processor.

My question is, why point to the last section and then intentionally jump to somewhere else? Why doesn't processor manufacturers reset CS:IP to 0000:0000? Then, they can write some initial instructions without any jump!!

Doesn't that make sense?

Comment: Related: [Why does 8085 start from 00000 whilst 8086 starts from FFFF0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380388/why-does-8085-start-from-00000-while-8086-from-ffff0) (I'd swear there was another question about this on one of the sister sites recently, but I can't recall which one, and the question was borderline off-topic there, so may have disappeared)

Comment: _FFFF:0000 which is the lowest 16bytes of the memory_? Are you sure that's the lowest. Seems to me that maps to FFFF0 (the last 16 bytes) of the 1mb area.

Comment: Probably should point out that on most 386's execution starts at `F000:FFF0`. In real mode that also maps to FFFF0 but most 386s start in unreal mode where segment F000 is associated with a descriptor that is mapped to a base address of FFFF0000 . When added to the offset FFF0 it yields an address of FFFFFFF0 which is 16 bytes below the 4gb mark.

Comment: ROM needs to be mapped to the reset address so the processor can reliably execute startup code.  Putting the ROM at the highest address and the RAM at the low addresses has many system design advantages.  Well, 40 years ago anyway, back when the notion of a chipset was still a distant futuristic idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all legacy interface :)

At 0000:0000 there is the IVT (interrupt vector table) which handles the interrupts(INT xx-instruction) with an array(address table) probably accessed by an extended `call  dword ptr [interrupt# * 4]` intruction in 8086-hardware, therefore int0(Divide by 0)=`[0*4]`, int1..., int2(NMI Interrupt="Non maskable interrupt" that can't be shut of by a CLI-instruction)=`[2*4]`, and so on.

At FFFF:0000 or F000:FFF0 (last 16 bytes before 1 Megabyte) there is the (cached copy of the) motherboard BIOS-ROM(read-only) in 8086-architecture going from F000:0000 to F000:FFFF(64 kByte). An arbitrary, but architecturally fixed, entry point into the initializiation routines of the BIOS.

See here: http://files.osdev.org/mirrors/geezer/osd/ram/index.htm#layout
and also here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29#Overview

I suppose setting the BIOS address to 0000:0000 would have complicated the circuits in the 8086-CPU for calculating the address of and accessing/calling interrupts with INT/IRET, which is very easy if the table is located at zero. Speed for interrupts=reduced circuitry seemed to be crucial without an MMU, because in 386-architecture you can set the interrupt table's address with the LIDT-instruction.